# Wrong way to display JSON to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON with this shape:

```
{
  "txs": [
    {
      "time": 1593748984,
      "size": 668,
      "input": [
        {
          "value": 75000000000,
          "address": "************************"
        },
        {
          "value": 6530483896,
          "address": "***********************"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "time": 1593748374,
      "size": 72470,
      "input": [
        {
          "value": 714488220,
          "address": "************************"
        },
        {
          "value": 700000000,
          "address": "******************************"
        },
        {
          "value": 571794323,
          "address": "*******************************"
        },
        {
          "value": 554727196,
          "address": "*********************************"
  ...
  }
```

I would like a dataframe of this shape with multiindex time,size:

```
time           size     value            address  
1593748984     668      75000000000      *********************
                        6530483896       ***********************
1593748374     72470    714488220        ****************************
                        700000000        *******************************
                        571794323        *****************************
                        554727196        ***************************
...
```

I tried some code to flatten the JSON and put it into a dataframe but could not do it.
I tried the following code:

```
def flatten_json_iterative_solution(dictionary):
    def unpack(parent_key, parent_value): 
        if isinstance(parent_value, dict):
            for key, value in parent_value.items():
                temp1 = parent_key + '_' + key
                yield temp1, value
        elif isinstance(parent_value, list):
            i = 0 
            for value in parent_value:
                temp2 = parent_key + '_'+str(i) 
                i += 1
                yield temp2, value
        else:
            yield parent_key, parent_value    

        dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items())))
        if not any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in dictionary.values()) and \
           not any(isinstance(value, list) for value in dictionary.values()):
            break

    return dictionary

frame = p.to_json(indent=2, sort_keys=False)
df = pd.Series(flatten_json_iterative_solution(dict(frame))).to_frame().reset_index()
```

Error:

```
 df = pd.Series(flatten_json_iterative_solution(dict(frame))).to_frame().reset_index()
```

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
> required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to read a json string then initialize a new dataframe from the `txs` list in this json, then using [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) explode the dataframe on column `input`, finally using [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) extract the values associated with the keys `value` and `address` from `input` column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(json_str)['txs'].tolist()).explode('input')
df1 = (
    df1.assign(
        value=df1['input'].str.get('value'),
        address=df1['input'].str.get('address'))
        .drop('input', 1).set_index(['time', 'size'])
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
                        value                            address
time       size                                                 
1593748984 668    75000000000           ************************
           668     6530483896            ***********************
1593748374 72470    714488220           ************************
           72470    700000000     ******************************
           72470    571794323    *******************************
           72470    554727196  *********************************
```

Comment: I am surprised how it is easy to understand and efficient while I spend hours to try something